# How to send email using FluentEmail and MailKit and specify SmtpClientOptions per tenant?

Tags: asp.net-core, smtp, mailkit

I can send emails using FluentEmail and Mailkit with the following code configured in startup.

```
            var smtpClientOptions = new SmtpClientOptions
            {
                Server = "***",
                Port = 587,
                UseSsl = false,
                RequiresAuthentication = true,
                User = "***",
                Password = "***"
            };

            services
                .AddFluentEmail("***")
                .AddRazorRenderer()
                .AddMailKitSender(smtpClientOptions);
```

However, I have a requirement to send emails to different customers (depending on tenant selected) using SmtpClientOptions specific to that tenant.

Is there a way I can override these options perhaps when sending the email, when I know the selected tenant?

Comment: Did you found out any solution???

Comment: @zsubzwary I ended up creating an instance of fluentemail is code rather that using startup.  Not pretty but couldnt work out how to do it another way.